# Handling white spaces in Request Parameter in springboot

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, hql

In my HQL i'm using

```
  queryListBuilder.append(" and f.nom like '%"+ nomFil +"%' ");
```

nomFil is a string that may contain white spaces between words.
when i send

```
 http://localhost:8080/list?nom=First Last
```

I got empty result.
Ps: in my DB the value exists in my target table.
is there any way to handel white spaces in request parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encode and decode the query params.

Ref : https://www.baeldung.com/java-url-encoding-decoding

Comment: best solution founded Thanks.

Comment: is there any solution if I cannot change the request? I have api that send the value with whitespace. But for reasons, I cannot modify the value (encode the param). Can we force the framework to accept the value?

Answer (score 2):

You should encode `nomFil` if using inside URL,as:

```
 URLEncoder.encode(nomFil, "UTF-8");
```

See [Percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

> Percent-encoding, also known as URL encoding, is a mechanism for encoding information in a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) under certain circumstances. Although it is known as URL encoding it is, in fact, used more generally within the main Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) set, which includes both Uniform Resource Locator (URL) and Uniform Resource Name (URN). As such, it is also used in the preparation of data of the application/x-www-form-urlencoded media type, as is often used in the submission of HTML form data in HTTP requests.